# Tensorflow tf.batch_matrix_diag (no attribute error)

Tags: tensorflow

One one machine, I have tensorflow version 0.11.0rc0 and on another machine tensorflow 0.10.0rc0. On the latter, `tf.batch_matrix_diag` works fine, but on the former, I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'batch_matrix_diag'`
---EDIT---

### The same error is occuring for `batch_cholesky` as well..

Could someone please explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use matrix_diag instead of batch_matrix_diag due to [this change](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/892deb2d7816af281b57a73a095886f75a259266).

Comment: There's a comment in the change saying "// Delete after 10mar2017.", so you probably don't want to avoid it even if there's a work around.  But it should be as simple as 

sed -i 's/tf.batch_matrix_diag/tf.matrix_diag/g' <files>

right?

Comment: Not sure. At least when I tried changing tf.batch_matmul to tf.matmul, it didn't work because the arguments required for both the functions aren't the same.

Comment: The change I noted above only updated the following functions:  
batch_matrix_band_part  
batch_matrix_diag  
batch_matrix_diag_part  
batch_matrix_set_diag  
batch_matrix_transpose, so batch_matmul and matmul are still different function.  If you look at the change I linked closely, it didn't seem like they have to change any arguments.

Comment: Well, batch_cholesky() is updated to cholesky() as well.  The gist is that you either have to roll back to an old version of tensorflow (not recommended) or just update all your api calls.  As mentioned before this should be quite straight forward with sed and regular expression replace.